# How to get PayPal Transaction Details in MPL android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

i am using MPL for adaptive payment. Everything is working fine but i want the PayPal Transaction Details, But it returned only paykey as a response after payment.

```
    public void PayPalActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            // The payment succeeded
            String payKey = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
            Log.d("payKey", payKey+"");
            this.paymentSucceeded(payKey);
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            this.paymentCanceled();
            break;
        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
            String errorID = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
            String errorMessage = intent.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            this.paymentFailed(errorID, errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

So there is any solution to get transaction details by paykey or something else to get transaction details.

Please give me some suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got paypal transaction details by Instant Payment Notification (IPN).
I have set an IPN URL like:-

```
PayPalAdvancedPayment advPayment = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
/*
some block of code
*/

 advPayment.setIpnUrl("IPN-Url");// this additional line i have attached to make code
```

And then it will send the transaction details to my server.